# How to add a method to a python class/object during debug session break in Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Needed to add a proc in my `class`/`object` on runtime to execute some code using inner variables and other private class methods (can't provide more details).

Was wondering how to achieve this so arrived at my own solution (provided as the current answer). Is there a better way of doing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @user2357112.
Following code works (executed from debug-evaluator dialog box launched during a debug break):

```
class someClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.element1 = '1'
    def pre_defined_method (self):
        print('in pre_defined_method - element1: {}'.format(self.element1))

def new_object_bound_method (self):
    print('in new_object_bound_method - element1: {}'.format(self.element1))

from  types import MethodType

obj = someClass()
setattr(obj, 'new_object_bound_method', 
            MethodType(new_object_bound_method, obj))
obj.pre_defined_method()
obj.new_object_bound_method()
obj.pre_defined_method()

try:
    obj2 = someClass()
    obj2.new_object_bound_method()
except Exception as e:
    print('"new_object_bound_method" is only bound to instance "obj" and not class "someClass"')
    print(e)

def new_class_bound_method(self):
    print('in new_class_bound_method - element1: {}'.format(self.element1))

someClass.new_class_bound_method = \
    MethodType(new_class_bound_method, None, someClass)

obj2.new_class_bound_method()
```

Output is:

```
in pre_defined_method - element1: 1
in new_object_bound_method - element1: 1
in pre_defined_method - element1: 1
"new_object_bound_method" is only bound to instance "obj" and not class "someClass"
'someClass' object has no attribute 'new_object_bound_method'
in new_class_bound_method - element1: 1
```

Comment: This might have looked like it works, but it's not doing what you think it does. When executing `o.y()`, `obj` is actually `someClass`, not `o`. Just doing `someClass.y = y` instead of the `setattr`/`MethodType` thing would set the method correctly.

Comment: @ShowStopper: `in` is part of the output.

Comment: user2357112: someClass is actually a pre-declared class in my code - not sure why you think its an object. Are you saying that `setattr(someClass, 'y', types.MethodType(y, someClass))` created a new object on the fly? I am so not sure how this works!

Comment: @barry_allen *"is actually a pre-declared class in my code - not sure why you think its an object"* – classes are objects in Python.

Comment: @Eli Korvigo - oh ok !!